# JavaScript: value of an object on a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a codecademy.com lesson that's teaching me how to build a bar graph with jQuery. The last set of instructions are to add a click event to $bar to display it's value. It explains

> Anonymous functions go like this: `function(arg) { code }`. In this
>   case, a .click handler will have e, the click event, as its argument,
>   so your implementation should have `function(e) { alert code }` within
>   the `.click()`.

Here's the function I'm supposed to modify

```
// Exercise 5
function addBarClickEvent($bar,value) {
    // add a click event to the bar that 
    // pops up an alert with the bars value
    $bar.click(
        // your code goes here!

        }
    );
}
```

I tried both of the solutions shown below but neither worked. The lesson doesn't provide a solution unfortunately. Can anyone help.

```
// Exercise 5
    function addBarClickEvent($bar,value) {
        // add a click event to the bar that 
        // pops up an alert with the bars value
        $bar.click(
            // your code goes here!
              alert($bar.value)       //my attempt
              alert(e.value)          //my second attempt
            }
        );
    }
```

I'm getting this error message

> Make sure to define the argument to .click as an anonymous function
>   that displays the alert.

Comment: @robbrit didn't work. I'm getting this error message "Make sure to define the argument to .click as an anonymous function that displays the alert."

Comment: @user1647484 look at Robin Maben's answer.  You forgot the `function(){` part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the value you want to display is the value that was passed at the time of binding

```
function addBarClickEvent($bar,value) {
    // add a click event to the bar that 
    // pops up an alert with the bars value
    $bar.click(function(){
       alert(value);
    });
}
```

If not -

```
$bar.click(function(){
   // get value somehow
  //$(this).data('some-value');
});
```

Comment: doesn't work. by the way, I'm getting this error message for all the attempts i've made. "Make sure to define the argument to .click as an anonymous function that displays the alert."

Comment: @user1647484: It *is* an anonymous function in both cases.

Comment: Maybe it's erroring on the missing `e` argument? The error message received certainly isn't a built-in javascript error, so I'm guessing the anonymous function needs to be constructed according to the instructions in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

The question tells you exactly what to do: "your implementation should have function(e) { alert code } within the .click()"

Just write what it says: `$bar.click(function(e) { alert(this.value); }`

Adjust the `this.value` depending on where the value actually is - I don't know and can't guess ;)